# Using Material-ui theme in styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Need to use theme spacing value in a styled component like below with no success.
When I first created it, style was applied to button. But now, no style is applied!

You can see it  here: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-theme-in-styled-comp-22r0m?file=/src/App.tsx:0-980).

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider,
  darken
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#6772e5"
    }
  },
  spacing: 8
});
const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  ${({ theme }) => `
    background-color: ${theme.palette.primary.main};
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: ${theme.spacing(2)};
    font-size: 13px;
    &:hover {
      background-color: ${darken(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.2)};
    }  
  `}
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
        <StyledButton>Customized</StyledButton>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Use the `StylesProvider` component as shown [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styled-component styles is overridden by the default JSS styles. By default, JSS styles is injected at the bottom of the `<head>` (higher CSS specificity). You can tell MUI to override JSS styles by putting your component tree inside `<StylesProvider injectFirst>`. See [controlling priority](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#controlling-priority-5).

```
// tell MUI to inject JSS style first, so styled-component can override it
<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <StyledButton>Customized</StyledButton>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
</StylesProvider>
```

[image: Edit 67232779/using-material-ui-theme-in-styled-component]

Comment: Very well!  But still padding-right is not using theme.spacing  value. How to fix it?

Comment: @killjoy theme.spacing(2) returns a number without unit. You need to append the `px` unit at the end. I've updated the live demo for you.

Comment: Can I use <StylesProvider injectFirst>  per component basis? Not in app scope. Or maybe can I override this behaviour for a specific component?

Comment: @killjoy No. `injectFirst` is used to set `injectFirstNode`, which is a module-scoped variable, so only app scope. [Source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1617f4ee72920d40d0b0f9dac34f90b82dadf4bf/packages/material-ui-styles/src/StylesProvider/StylesProvider.js#L66)